# OpenSSH - automatic server private and public keys creation

Tags: debian, ssh, system-installation, openssh

In RedHat based distributions you can set the type of server private and public keys which the init script will automatically create, with the variable `AUTOCREATE_SERVER_KEYS` variable.

Can you do this in Debian and if yes, how?

Comment: Host keys? Debian's `openssh-server` package creates them when installed, I'm not sure why you'd want to (re)create them when starting the server, since resetting the host's identity every time seems counterproductive

Comment: I want to do it as part of an ssh-hardening procedure. I'm replacing the DH primes in `moduli` file, but I want to be able to customize the auto-creation and exclude weak keys.

Comment: As @likkachu said, you happen to do that only once (or not often at least) absolutely not at each server restart.

Comment: Ok, so the answer is `No`.

Comment: While technically it can be done, the proper answer is it is not advisable. You can always delete them, and run the appropriate script/or `dpkg-reconfigure` (would have to test). I would do it only (re)deploying image templates of VMs for them not to have all the same key, not at every restart.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro your're right, the host keys can be reconfigured with:
```
rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian, regenerating host keys can happen with:

```
rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

Comment: I nevertheless insist it is not advisable doing that at every single boot time, but only at deployment time. +1